# Mount a former MDADM RAID1 partition to backup data - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, mdadm

After a crash, lost mdadm RAID 1 and need to backup sdc3 partition to another disk. How should be correct steps to make it done without pain? No longer using RAID 1 on this fresh new Ubuntu 19.10 as shown below (of course, mdadm is installed):

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : inactive sdc3[0](S)
      937567232 blocks super 1.2
```

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     62500000 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
Partition[1] :     15624192 sectors at   1937899520 (type fd)
Partition[2] :   1875396608 sectors at     62502912 (type fd)
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disco /dev/sdc: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 setores
Disk model: SAMSUNG HD103SJ 
Unidades: setor de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho de setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho E/S (mínimo/ótimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de rótulo do disco: dos
Identificador do disco: 0x0004af66

Dispositivo Inicializar     Início        Fim    Setores Tamanho Id Tipo
/dev/sdc1                     2048   62502047   62500000   29,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2               1937899520 1953523711   15624192    7,5G fd Linux RAID a
/dev/sdc3                 62502912 1937899519 1875396608  894,3G fd Linux RAID a

Partições lógicas fora da ordem do disco.(Logic partitions out of order)
```

Tried to assemble but partition is busy:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 --update=uuid /dev/sdc3
mdadm: /dev/sdc3 is busy - skipping
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with diskinternals partition recovery and diskinternals linux reader